# saveAll() with return ID

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a form where people sign up/make a payment all together.

I'm using saveAll() to add both a row to the payments table, and a row to the users table.  The only problem is, my user_id isn't getting saved along with the payment data.

Whats the best way to get the newly created user_id and save it with the payment data?

Answer (score 0):

```
if($this->Post->saveAll($post)) {
    $user_id=$this->Post->inserted_id; //get last insert_id
}
```

Then bind this $user_id with payment data and save.